# How to join all variable observations of a data.frame and save them to a raw .txt file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, word-cloud

I want to make a Word Cloud and I have a .csv file of emails, with 7945 observations and 22 variables. One of these variables include the RawText of the emails. I want to make a Word Cloud out of this RawText. Yet, I don't know how to join the rows of this variable (RawText of all emails since 1 row has a raw text of 1 email) and save everything to 1 .txt file so I could proceed with the Word Cloud. Could somebody help ? Or maybe I'm thinking wrong way and I could somehow do it in other way? Here is a snapshot of my data:
[image: data]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but the `tm` package has methods to deal with text data. Perhaps, you can look it up and some tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

To join all row of a column, you can use `paste` with the `collapse` parameter.

```
# Combine all, with separator "linebreak"
AllInOne <- paste(D$RawData, collapse='\n') 
# Store it in a txt file
write.table(AllInOne, 'PathToFile', col.names=false, row.names=false, quote=false)
```